# Installed Ubuntu and lost access to Windows

Tags: dual-boot, windows

I installed it by using a load of unallocated space on a completely separate hard drive than the one Windows is installed to.

When I choose Windows on the boot menu I get this:

> 'Invalid EFI path'

Any idea why this is?

EDIT:
Here is information from boot info script.
http://paste.ubuntu.com/1202156/

I think it might be because I have more than 4 partitions on the drive? Although I am not sure what the one labelled as '**unknown**' is at all.

Comment: Which boot menu are you using? If you are selecting the Windows entry in Grub[2] then try switching the boot order in your UEFI/BIOS and see if Windows boots on its own.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you using EFI, install grub-efi: `apt-get install grub-efi`
2. Use "Separate /efi" option of [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).
3. Then force your BIOS to boot into Grub EFI partition

This works for me every time. Good luck!